# Validate get_tax_totals in checkout

Tags: php, if-statement, woocommerce

I am trying to add an if statement to reflect a text when the tax = 0. I took the template from cart/review-order from line :93:

```
        <tr class="tax-total">
            <th><?php if( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() == 0 ){ echo 'Vat reverse (0%)'; } else { echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); } ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>
```

I added `<?php if( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() == 0 ){ echo 'Vat reverse (0%)'; } else { echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); } ?>` but it skips the if() and shows in all situations the else statement. I have tried different ways to get the tax totals, but all in the same result. What goes wrong here?

Comment: What does `var_dump(WC()->cart->get_tax_totals());` give you? Because I'm gonna guess that a function called `get_tax_totals` won't return just one number.

Comment: [`get_tax_totals()`](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartget_tax_totals/) returns an `array`...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I found it: is should be `get_total_tax()`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.